# Pyshark interfaces in Live Capture

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyshark

I need to capture live packets from more than one interface using Live Capture module in Pyshark.
cap=pyshark.LiveCpature(interface='eth0')

How can I add one more interface using Live Capture. 
Ex: I need to capture packets from interfaces eth0 and eth1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do that directly in the constructor at the moment in pyshark, but you can do:

```
cap = pyshark.LiveCapture()
cap.interfaces = ['eth0', 'eth1']
```

This should work.
I've opened an issue in the pyshark repo to add this feature.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Provided code working fine.

Comment: The newest version (0.3.6) supports using a list of interfaces in the constructor.